# post error 400 whille using firebase authentication for signup page in angular throwing error

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoginForm } from 'src/app/types/LoginForm';
import { RegisterForm } from 'src/app/types/RegisterForm';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  form:RegisterForm={
    email:'',
    password:'',
    confirmPassword:""
  }

  matchedPassword:boolean=true;
  submit(){
  if(this.form.password!=this.form.confirmPassword){
    this.matchedPassword=false;
    return;
  }

const auth = getAuth();
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.form.email, this.form.password)
  .then((userCredential) => {
    // Signed in 
    console.log(userCredential);
    console.log(this.form)
    // const user = userCredential.user;
    // ...
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    const errorCode = error.code;
    const errorMessage = error.message;
    console.log("AUth errror");
    
    // ..
  });
   
  }
}
```

I have been trying to use firebase auth with angular while using it i got a error in cnsole i.e. post error 400 whille using firebase authentication for signup page in angular throwing error in createUserWithEmailAndPassword() method in register.component.ts. which is provided above. Please help me solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, and I inspect the console > network.
it says that the minimum length of the password is 6, hope this can help you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33741977)